# "sudo iw reg get" still shows "country 00" after updating "/etc/default/crda"

Tags: wireless, 16.04

As part of an effort to troubleshoot Wi-Fi issue on an Intel Next Unit Computing(NUC) running Ubuntu 16.04, I updated my `etc/default/crda`, adding `REGDOMAIN=US` to the end of the file and reboot it.

However, `sudo iw reg get` still returns `00` (not set):

```
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
```

Does anyone know why this would not be changing my REGDOMAIN?

Comment: Is the package *wireless-regdb* installed? `sudo dpkg -s wireless-regdb`

Comment: Yep! `Status: install ok installed`

Answer (score 7):

Often, a country code is set in the chip of the wireless device. For example, I recently bought a USB wireless and, as I studied `dmesg`, I noticed:

> cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: CN

I am located in the USA.

Can you set the CRDA after the computer is started?

```
sudo iw reg set US
iw reg get
```

If so, you can set it in rc.local:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Add a last line, right above exit 0, to read:

```
iw reg set US
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

If this is ineffective, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Check after a reboot:

```
iw reg get
```